# API Error Code: 100 using passport-facebook in nodejitsu

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, nodejitsu

I've been developing this app during the last few weeks, which uses a login system based on [passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/), and everything was working fine on my dev computer until I decided to test it on nodejitsu.

The error that im getting is:

- API Error Code: 100  API Error
- Description: Invalid parameter  Error
- Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted

The redirect_uri is: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftookie_beta.jit.su%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email%2Cuser_website&client_id=399936936740982&type=web_server

Which looks fine to me, so I'm kinda lost.

This was the configuration that i was using on my local machine:

[image]

And this is the configuration that I have now:

[image]

Does anyone knows what's going on, or what i'm missing here ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your Site URL is wrong. Shouldn't it point to http://your-subdomain.jit.su?

Comment: I tried that too, but it says:

Error
Site URL must be a URL with a valid domain.

Answer (score 0):

Hasn't nodejitsu dropped its service as it was bought out by GoDaddy :(

Link: https://blog.nodejitsu.com/nodejitsu-joins-godaddy/